# Facing this type of error 'Insufficient privileges' in SQL developer

Tags: sql, oracle, debugging

```
Connecting to the database DEV.
Executing PL/SQL: CALL DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP.CONNECT_TCP( '10.212.242.121', '4000' )
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP", line 68
ORA-06512: at line 1
This session requires DEBUG CONNECT SESSION and DEBUG ANY PROCEDURE user privileges.
Process exited.
Disconnecting from the database DEV.
```

Comment: And what is the question? The error message is clear: `This session requires DEBUG CONNECT SESSION and DEBUG ANY PROCEDURE user privileges`

Answer (score 1):

As you were told:

> This session requires DEBUG CONNECT SESSION and DEBUG ANY PROCEDURE user privileges.

Connect as a privileged user (SYS) and grant those privileges to user which will be using them:

```
SQL> connect sys as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> grant debug connect session to scott;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> grant debug any procedure to scott;

Grant succeeded.

SQL>
```

Comment: in my system SQLPLUS is not installed. Can you please provide me another solution which is related to oracle SQL developer

Comment: You can do the same in SQL Developer; no difference at all.

Comment: facing below error - Error starting at line : 1 in command -
grant debug connect session to ERFDEV
Error report -
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to perform a database operation without
           the necessary privileges.
*Action:   Ask your database administrator or designated security
           administrator to grant you the necessary privileges

Comment: Exactly; I told you, you have to be connected as a privileged user (such as SYS); you can't do it with your "normal" user.

Comment: @LittleBitDeveloper _"Can you please provide me another solution which is related to oracle SQL developer "_   The solution provided is the issuance of specific sql commands.  The client (sqlplus, SQL Dev, etc, etc) simply take the commands as keyed in and pass it to the database for processing.  The database doesn't care which client is being used.  The commands are processed by the database, not the client.

Comment: @LittleBitDeveloper it us highly unlikely that you can sign-in as SYS or any other privileged user. However, that does not reduce that requirement. So the answer to "*Can you please provide me another solution... "*  is talk with your DBA and request the necessary grants. Be prepared to explain why you need then, and perhaps for how long.  **You have no other option**.